# Procedures doesn't give any output (scheme)

Tags: racket

Im using emacs and mzscheme as interpreter

```
Welcome to Racket v8.2 [cs]
> (define (square a) (* a a))
> square 4
#<procedure:square>
> 4
```

I just finished setting up emacs with mzscheme, combinations are working well but my procedures doesn't seem to work. Tried everything i could find.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct way to call the procedure?

Comment: You're not calling `square` but evaluating the variable and get the procedure function printed and then 4 since that is a separate expression that is self evaluation.  In JS instead of calling `square(4)` you write `square; 4` instead you'll get `[Function: square]` and `4` . In Scheme you write `(square 4)`

Comment: The `[cs]` means you're using the Chez Scheme backend, not the old mzscheme one (`[bc]`) (and why did you have mit-scheme tagged?)